# Marginal Likelihood of independent priors

Tags: bayesian, metropolis-hastings

Let $p(m,n|\pmb{X}) \propto f(m,n)$. Now using a metropolis Hasting's algorithm, I need to sample values for $(m,n)$. I plan on using a Bivariate normal distribution as the proposal function. I have the following question

1. Under which conditions can the off-diagonal terms of the covariance matrix be zero ? $m$ and $n$ are hyperparameters of the model from which $\pmb{X}$ is generated and their prior distribution is said to be independent. Is this condition sufficient for choosing such a covariance ?

Comment: The choice of the proposal is completely free, so even when $m$ and $n$ are correlated in the posterior (forget about the prior correlation), you are OK with an independent proposal. At least in theory.

Comment: How is the title related to the question?